# JsonDeserializer<Date> is not invoked

Tags: java, date, jackson

I am making a web application which makes a REST call to return me the list of order. The order has list of products and each product has expiry date. So, something like this

```
{
   "order": 123,
   "products" :[
     {
        ...
        "expiryDate": "2015 January 01",
        ...
     }
    ]
}
```

I obviously needed to generate the POJO and because there are so many fields I choose this tool http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

I want to convert this String date to java.util.Date and to do that, I have created a custom date serializer and put this annotation on product expiry setter method

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomJsonDateDeserializer.class)
public void setExpiryDate(Date date) {
   ...
}

// Different Class
public class CustomJsonDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date>
{
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser,
            DeserializationContext deserializationcontext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        ....
    }
}
```

However, deserialize() method doesn't get invoked at all. I also put in the @JsonDeserialize to the field where it is declared but it is still not work.

Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks for the help

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. Where and how is Jackson involved?

Comment: Using Jackson library to de-serialize my REST response. The @JsonDeserialize annotation is from com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation package.